# How to move the axes back in Plot?

Tags: plotting

I'd like to draw some curves using Plot, and I tried follow codes:

```
 Plot[Table[n/Sqrt[\[Pi]] Exp[-n^2 x^2], {n, {3, 5, 7}}], {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
 AxesStyle -> 
 Directive[Arrowheads[0.04], GrayLevel[0.7], Thick, Opacity[1]],
 Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-0.7, 4.5}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, RegionFunction -> Function[{x}, Abs[x] < 1]]
```

Then it comes out this:

[image]

Which I confused is that the gray axes are in the front of the black curves(esp. for the x axes). How can I move the axes backward to show my curve well?

Comment: You could make two plots. One without data and one without axes and use `Show` or `Overlay`. No time atm for a full answer with example.

Comment: You only have to add the option ` Method -> ("AxesInFront" -> False)`

Comment: @eldo thank you. The problem has been solved

Comment: @Johu `Overlay` is ok, but `Show` can't solve this problem, because `Show` will apply the same Graphics options to all objects.